# google recaptcha getResponse() is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

Made a form and used Google recaptcha. I submit form using ajax and check response via PHP(CURL), I also check other things on PHP like if username is unique. when username is already exists in database, PHP gives response 'error' to ajax. Now if the response is 'error', google recaptcha should reload.

I used `grecaptcha.reset();` under 'success' condition of ajax but I got

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponse' of undefined

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/myphp.php',
            data: {
                action: action,                 
                grecaptcha:grecaptcha.getResponse() // <-- IT WAS WORKING BEFORE 15th JAN 
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) { 
                data = JSON.parse(data);                  
                if(data.res=='success'){}
                if(data.res=='error')
                {
                  grecaptcha.reset(); // <-- IT WAS WORKING BEFORE 15th JAN                      
                }
            },
            error: function (MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }

         });
```

Comment: check for captcha library?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponse' of undefined` means that `grecaptcha` is undefined which means the library isn't included in the page.

Comment: I am using this code to include google captcha api
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?ver=4.4.2'></script>